# Use google Api to Edit google docs without uploading to google drive in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I am trying to open and edit a Microsoft word document in google docs from my .NET MVC project.
Currently, whenever I open the document it is uploaded to the google drive of the user and then opens for editing.
I am using the Google Drive API v3.

I want to open and edit the document without being uploaded in the drive i.e. There should be no trace of the file in the drive. The file is opened and edited directly without being created or uploaded in the Google drive.

Comment: It looks like you would like to get a free version of MS Word.

Comment: As long as the file is accessible via a `http://` or `https://` URL then you should be able to open it in Docs as far as I know. I don't think you're required to store it in Google Drive specifically. Have you researched this at all? You say "opened and edited directly", but you don't say where from. Where is the file being stored currently?

Answer (score 1):

The google drive api is a file storage API. You can upload, download files and create files.  It does not have the ability to directly edit the constants of any files directly this is out of scope for this API.

The Google docs api would allow you to edit google doc type files but not a MS word file.  You would need to upload the file to Google drive convert it to a google docs file then use the google docs api on it for editing programmatic.

If you want to open a MS word document why not look for a library that handles opening ms word documents.